# How can we warm more than one lambda server with a cronjob?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-lambda, serverless

People often say that using event bridge cronjob to keep lambda warm only will keep 1 lambda running and requests that cannot be handled by it will experience cold starts. But, [Open Next offers the possibility of having as many warmed lambda as needed using Event Bridge cron jobs](https://open-next.js.org/inner_workings/warming). The documentation states that there will be a separate lambda for warming the main lambda, but I didn't get how can this keep more than one lambda alive.

If the warmer function just pings the server function, how does Open Next make sure that each ping can always hit a different lambda?

Comment: Keeping Lambda functions warm with cron jobs like that is the old "hacky" way to accomplish that before AWS added provisioned concurrency support to AWS Lambda. Just use provisioned concurrency now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html And I agree, that thing you linked to doesn't sound like it would accomplish what you want.

Comment: Though it is hacky, it is still less than a dollar for keeping 50 lambdas warm.

Comment: Why would you use that method though, when the new method is free, and built into the system so all you have to do is set a number and forget about it.

Comment: From what I understood from the pricing page, it would cost about 10 dollars per month for each instance when using provisioned concurrency. So it's not free x_x hahaha.

For the 50 instances from that example, it would be 50 dollars vs less than 1 dollar.

Comment: I think your 1 dollar calculation is leaving out the cost of having 50 functions constantly running. You are only calculating the cost of the tool that is keeping those functions warm.

Comment: isn't lambda charged by invocation + gb per second?  So this 1 dollar from this docs is for having 50 idle functions. The price for "real invocation" doesn't matter here (and is the same in both cases), it is 50 dollars for idle vs 1 dollar for idle (if this method really keeps 50 instances warmed).

Comment: The cost of the tool is a lot less actually, less than 17 cents for what they showed.

Comment: So what tool are you using that can keep 50 concurrent instances of your function warm? The tool you linked in your question that seemed dubious that it would actually keep more than 1 instance warm?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking. Open-next is actually a pretty solid open-source initiative, so, if they said this can keep n lambdas alive, I believe them. But then comes my question of how can they guarantee that this method will be able to ping n different lambdas.

Comment: Test it and find out if it works?

Comment: Yeah, it works. The `Total concurrent executions` matches what you configure on SST (the framework that uses OpenNext), which means each ping from the warmer functions hits different lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research on how lambda works, I found the answer.

> on each concurrent request, Lambda provisions a separate instance of your execution environment.

This means each lambda instance can handle 1 request at a time, so, for having 50 instances alive, the warmer function from [this tutorial](https://open-next.js.org/inner_workings/warming) will make 50 requests to the server function each time it is invoked by the EventBridge cronjob. They will need to be handled by 50 different lambdas since they will be concurrent.

This explains why they need a warmer function instead of just warming the server function directly with the cronjob.